# Escape within su and awk

Tags: bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash
VM=`su joe -c "VBoxManage list vms | awk '{split($0,a,"\""); print a[2]; exit}'"`
echo $VM
```

I like to get the first VM name from joe's perspective. How do properly escape?

VBoxmanage list vms output is:

```
"VM 1" {serial num}
"VM 2" {serial num}
```

etc

Echo should ouput VM 1.

Comment: What is output of `VBoxManage list vms` command what is your expected output from this command?

Comment: Output is: "VM 1" {b3267302-6b59-40a5-acb6-27e7f9676b91}\n"VM 2" {... I like to get the first VM name (VM 1).

Comment: You should edit your question to include that text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
VM=$(su joe -c 'VBoxManage list vms | cut -d \" -f2 | sed 1q')
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways round this. Here's one:

```
VM=$(su joe -c "VBoxManage list vms | awk -F'\"' '{print \$2; exit}'")
```

Instead of using split, just change the field separator. Depending on how many lines of output there are, the call to exit may not be necessary either. If there is only one line, awk will exit after it processes it anyway. I have also changed the backticks around the whole command to the preferred `$()` syntax.

Comment: Good idea, but: bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"' bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: As I said above, it would be helpful to see the output of your command in the question but yes, you're right, this needs fixing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape `"` and `$` both:

```
VM=$(su joe -c "VBoxManage list vms | awk -F '\"' '{print \$2; exit}'")
echo "$VM"
VM 1
```